# Unable to perform Microsoft OAuth from iOS devices in Outlook Add-in

Tags: ios, outlook, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, outlook-web-addins

I have been trying to get my head around this problem. I have created an Outlook add-in using React.js and now I am trying to use Microsoft OAuth2.0 in this add-in. I was using MSAL.js for that purpose which was working fine on All the platforms like Outlook for Desktop, Web app and android application except for iOS devices.

After debugging the code I came to know that the callback function that is used to be called after performing the Auth is not actually getting called for iOS devices. here is the code

```
    const userAgentApp = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(config)

    const authCallback = (error, response) => {
        console.log({ error, response })
        sendRequest({ error, response })
        if (!error) {
            if (response.tokenType === "id_token") {
                localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", "yes")
            } else {
                // The tokenType is access_token, so send success message and token.
                Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({ status: "success", result: response.accessToken }))
            }
        } else {
            handleErrors(error, Office)
        }
    }

    userAgentApp.handleRedirectCallback(authCallback)
```

After removing the dependency over MSAL.js and changing my code as

```
Office.initialize = () => {
        if (!location.href.match(/access_token/gi)) {
            location.href = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token+id_token&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20People.Read%20User.read&state=9Eu8.9Sz_LDcQzsZ&nonce=Hb77t324t4ugugHgUYguy2342`
        } else if (location.href.match(/access_token/gi)) {
            const response = getUrlParameters()
            if (response.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
                loginUser(response, Office)
            } else if (response.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({ status: "failure", result: response }))
            }
        }
    }
```

Again this is working fine for all platforms except iOS devices. For **iPhone 6** it is redirecting back to the Microsoft login screen and on debugging I came to know that there is no data in response url while there should be **access_token** and **id_token** etc. One more thing is for **iPhone X** when I click on login  with Outlook button, the dialogApi open's a window and keep start blinking not even showing the Microsoft login screen.

here is the **dialogApi** code

```
const dialogLoginUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '') + '/auth/outlook/login.html'
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
            dialogLoginUrl,
            { height: 70, width: 40 },
            (result) => {
                console.log("dsad5asd65asd65as6d5", { result })
                    loginDialog = result.value
                    loginDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processLoginMessage)
                    loginDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, processLoginDialogEvent)
                }
        )
```

Comment: What is the browser version for iPhone devices? Did you read about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-known-issues-safari-browser ? Did you read "Test and debug Office Add-ins" docs from MS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins

Did you setup proper logging? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-logging?tabs=javascript

Comment: This seems to be an issue with OAuth rather than add-ins.You specified an issue with displayDialogAsync, what is the URL you were trying to hit?

Comment: @LukeDuda Thanks for the help. I have read all the docs that you have mentioned. Also, we have removed the dependency over MSAL.js completely.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I should have posted the dialogLoginUrl which is something like https://example.com/auth/outlook/login.html which is working fine and after it opens the code in the 2nd block of my question executes and works fine for All other platforms except iOS. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @LukeDuda Devices that have used for testing are not mine, but they are updated to the latest possible version specially iPhone 6. As I have checked on App Store there were on updates available that time.